# Как остановить WCF-сервис?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

У меня есть WCF-сервис и консольное приложение (хост). Код хоста:

```
private static void StartHost()
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8873/MyWCF/");

    using (ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCF), baseAddress))
    {
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfService.IMyWCF), new WSHttpBinding(), "MyWCF");

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        selfHost.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        selfHost.Abort();
        selfHost.Close();
    }
}
```

Это работает, я могу отправлять сообщения моему сервисe через клиентское приложение.

Но если я нажимаю Enter и закрываю хост, то WCF-служба продолжает работать! Запросы от клиента проходят, ответы возвращаются.. В диспетчере задач я вижу запущенный процесс IIS Express, в трее в списке запущенных сайтов с IIS я так же вижу свой сервис.. Почему так происходит, ведь я использую конструкцию using и даже вызываю методы Abort() и Close().. Как я могу полностью остановить сервис? Проблема в том, что сервис использует некоторые dll из решения, служба их не "отпускает". 
Спасибо за любую помощь, ссылки

Клиентский код:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8873/MyWCF/");
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var wcf = ChannelFactory<IMyWCF>.CreateChannel(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
```

Comment: `WCF-сервис и консольное приложение (хост)` ...  `если я нажимаю Enter и закрываю хост, то WCF-служба продолжает работать` - почему службе должно быть дело до какой-то консоли и фактом её закрытия?

Comment: @tym32167, но ведь консольное приложение запускает хостинг этой службы, а по окончанию своей работы закрывает его.
Сейчас разобрался и понял, что такое происходит только при запуске из VS в дебаге. При запуске exe из bin, IIS вообще не запускается. Однако теперь клиент не может достучаться до сервиса, пишет "Прослушивание на "http://localhost:8873/MyWCF.svc" не выполняла ни одна конечная точка, которая могла бы принять сообщение." Хотя браузер успешно стучится по этому адресу и видно, что сервис работает.

Comment: Клиенсткий код не менял, добавлю его сейчас в тело вопроса

Comment: я не знаю, что вы делаете. У вас то ли служба, то ли консоль, то ли IIS - но есть же [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application), вы смотрели её? Например, раздел про `Press Ctrl+F5 to run the service.`?